# Telerik-RadGrid DetailTables in ASP.NET Website

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I'm trying to generate a details table linked to a parent row like in this example:

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/data-binding/programmatic-hierarchy/defaultvb.aspx?show-source=true

This is my code:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid_ElencoAssistance" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource_ElencoAssistance" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter="True" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="20" GridLines="None">
<MasterTableView DataKeyNames="ID" NoMasterRecordsText="No Records">

      <DetailTables>
          <telerik:GridTableView runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" >
              <Columns>
                  <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Targa" HeaderText="Numberplate"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
              </Columns>
          </telerik:GridTableView>
      </DetailTables>

      <Columns>
          <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Targa" HeaderText="Numberplate"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
      </Columns>

</MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

Where am I wrong? Thank you

Comment: What output do you get now? Why is it wrong?

Comment: @Ross The parent table looks good but when I watch to the details, the nested table (DetailsTables) become white and I don't know why.